# Double module definition error

Tags: android, c, android-ndk

I am attempting to compile my C code using Android NDK. I downloaded and installed as suggested on the [Android developer NDK Page](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html), and attempted to compile as prescribed, but there seems to be some problem, and I don't seem to know what it is.

```
 *** Command Line compile code **
C:\cygwin\android-ndk-r7c>ndk-build -C C:\Users\BoosterJack\workspace\workAndroid
    Android NDK: Trying to define local module 'stdc++' in C:/cygwin/android-ndk-r7c/sources/cxx-stl/system/Android.mk.
    Android NDK: But this module was already defined by C:/cygwin/android-ndk-r7c/sources/cxx-stl/system/Android.mk.
    make: Entering directory `C:/Users/BoosterJack/workspace/workAndroid'
    C:/cygwin/android-ndk-r7c/build/core/build-module.mk:34: *** Android NDK: Aborting.    .  Stop.
    make: Leaving directory `C:/Users/BoosterJack/workspace/workAndroid'
```

My make file is also a simple one. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
# Include makefiles here.
include $(LOCAL_PATH)/Android.mk 

   LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

   include $(CLEAR_VARS)

   LOCAL_MODULE    := NativeLibjni
   LOCAL_SRC_FILES := NativeLib.c

   include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

## UPDATE

When I remove the line from my makefile, include $(LOCAL_PATH)/Android.mk, I get the correct output which is

```
C:\Users\BoosterJack>ndk-build -C C:\Users\BoosterJack\workspace\workAndroid
make: Entering directory `C:/Users/BoosterJack/workspace/workAndroid'
"Compile thumb : NativeLibjni <= NativeLib.c
SharedLibrary  : libNativeLibjni.so
Install        : libNativeLibjni.so => libs/armeabi/libNativeLibjni.so
make: Leaving directory `C:/Users/BoosterJack/workspace/workAndroid'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why did you include Android.mk in itself using `include $(LOCAL_PATH)/Android.mk`

Comment: That was my attempt to include the Android.mk file I had prepared. Is that wrong?

Comment: You should run ndk-build from the directory where Android.mk is placed. Android.mk gets included wherever it needs by the build system, you don't include it. You can refer to ndk/samples there is a hello-jni project